# fopen("file.csv"): failed to open steam: Permission denied

Tags: php, web

my program is put in server and run it. I already set the folder permission is 777 and the user is root. Also, php.ini allow_uri_fopen is on. But still not working.

the program is related open, modify and save the .csv file and than download. In the error_log show the permission error.

I use Winscp to remote the server and change the file.

what setting need modify? Or coding need change?

thanks you everybody.
My English is not very good. I am so sorry.

Comment: Set file permission to 644 `chmod 644 filename.php` not `777` or `chown -R www-data:www-data folder-name`

Comment: @LasVegasCoder Thank you for your respond. When i change the permission to 644, I cannot access the web page on the browser.

Comment: Note that you don't change folder to `644` only files can be changed to `644` .  You can change folder to `755`

Comment: @LasVegasCoder thank you. I change the folder to 755.

Comment: You are welcome @yso1955

Comment: if want to solve the fopen() permission error, what setting in php.ini or http.conf file need modify?

Comment: Can you share your code to help you to fix it.  make that sure your script has `fopen( 'filename', 'r');` // for read, w for write, a+ for append.

Answer (score 0):

### fopen Permission Denied Error

Try:

```
$filename = "Full_list_of_PDF_Generation_Report.csv";

$file = fopen ($filename, "w+") or die("Cannot open $filename");

    fputcsv($file, explode(',', "Full list of PDF Generation for $month/$year"));
    fputcsv($file, explode(',', "Form Name,Form Type,Uid,Update Time,Attached"));

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        fputcsv($file, explode(',',$row["form_attached"]));
    }

    fputcsv($file, explode(',', ",,,Total no.".",".$total_num));

    fclose($file);
```

+++++++++
Normally You will do a sanity check to make sure that file exist before reading it;

```
if(file_exists(dirname($filename))){

//r=read; w=write; a=append
    fopen($filename, 'r+');  
   ...
}
```

*Set file permission to 644*

```
chmod 644 filename.php` not `777`
```

or

```
chown -R www-data:www-data folder-name
```

or

```
chown -R username:groupname folder
```

NOTE: Directory permission is `755` *mostly*. Set file permission for files such as *.php to `644` and config files such as `wp-config.php, database.php`, should be set to `600`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I already set the .php file to 644 and directory to 755. But the fopen() permission denied error still exist. What other setting need modify?

Comment: Can you explain what you were doing that generate error? sample code will help to figure it out.

Comment: thank you for you respond. my program make a .csv file using mysql data. It will modify the .csv content    each times and than save the .csv file for download to user. The code will post to below for you refer.

Comment: the below program can run on my localhost computer using xampp. But, put the program to server, it not work about the fopen().'

Comment: thank you for your answer. my code and your new code is working in local computer but not work on the server. Our problem is the fopen() permission denied error. I set the folder or file to 755 or 644 not work. So, i think this problem is related the permission setting while not related code. Anyway, thank you for your respond and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

this is my php code

$file = fopen ("Full_list_of_PDF_Generation_Report.csv", "w+");

```
        fputcsv($file, explode(',', "Full list of PDF Generation for $month/$year"));
        fputcsv($file, explode(',', "Form Name,Form Type,Uid,Update Time,Attached"));

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            fputcsv($file, explode(',',$row["form_attached"]));
        }

        fputcsv($file, explode(',', ",,,Total no.".",".$total_num));

        fclose($file);
```